# Are any Christian philosophers working on an argument from causation that works with Quantum Physics?

Tags: philosophy, thomism

A chat yesterday informed me that Aquinas' [argument from causation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wefohtJBnN8) was "too Newtonian" to work for modern atheists and only works in our friendly neighborhood eminently perceivable dimension.

So, my question is, have any Christian philosophers been working on moving these particular goalposts into quantum space? And not just in a "well who created the multi-verse" way or an abject denial.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes, there is the excellent Wolfgang Smith

Comment: I'm puzzled by the claim that Aquinas' argument from causation is too Newtonian since Thomists often point out that Newtonian physics effectively denies final causation as a real thing.

Comment: "Who created the multiverse?" is an excellent response to this - or "who defined the rules of quantum physics?". Modern physics doesn't let you escape questions of causality at all. One still must either deal with the absurdities of a causal loop or an infinite regress of cause.